# .Net - How to write a Stream to a file in specified location

Tags: .net, ftp, download, stream

I am trying to download a zip file from an FTP location to a directory in the server harddisk.

I am getting the zip file as a ReponseStream from the FTP location.

How can i write this zip file to a specified directory. I can't say what the size of this file will be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use `WebClient.DownloadFile("remote file", "local file")`? It's so much simpler.